# What is ResourceFetcher in mocking an object in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mocking, xctest

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzlz3Bx-NzM) from Jon Reid. I have followed all his code until I got to an error. I have no idea where `ResourceFetcher` is defined and why this is not working for me! Here is the code:

In ViewController:

```
-(void) fetchResources
{

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];



    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:string
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
             NSLog(@"%@",(NSDictionary *)responseObject);
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

             NSLog(@"Error in retrieve data");

         }
     ];
}
```

In MockAFNetworkingGET:

```
@implementation MockAFNetworkingGET



-(AFHTTPRequestOperation *) GET : (NSString*) URLString
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                            success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id respondObject)) success
                            failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error))failure
{


    self.callCount += 1;

    self.URLString = URLString;
    self.parameters = parameters;
    self.success = success;
    self.failure = failure;

    return self.fakeReturnValue;

}


@end
```

In ResourceFetcherTests:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "MockAFNetworkingGET.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ResourceFetcherTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation ResourceFetcherTests




-(void) testFetchResources_shouldCallGet
{
    id mockGet = [[MockAFNetworkingGET alloc]init];
    ResourceFetcher *sut = [[ResourceFetcher alloc] initWithGETManager:mockGet];
    //ResourceFetcher is not existing and giving me compiler error!!

}

@end
```

I have copy and paste all the code here from tutorial. `ResourceFetcher` is not known here. I google but nothing come up! Is it a build in library or I need to define it somewhere or import some library?

Here is link to slide show:

https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/dbce1540217c01328c641a1ab62a9337/Controlling_Dependencies_4-3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

ResourceFetcher is the name of the System Under Test that holds the `fetchResources` method. It's just a made-up name for the class. (By the way, avoid direct networking calls in view controllers.) Feel free to contact me for questions about my stuff. This isn't really appropriate for StackOverflow.